# Woocommerce: Agregar etiqueta html debajo de un campo

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Estoy tratando de agregar una etiqueta html "< p >" debajo del campo Billing_Address_2. Me recomendaron hacerlo con un hook y esto es lo que intente:

```
    function aviso_rojo() {
echo '<p class="aviso_rojo" style="color:red;float:left;display:none">Hola Mundo</p>';
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_billing_address_2_field', 'aviso_rojo' );
```

Lo que deberia pasar es que agregue una etiqueta p en rojo debajo del campo de direccion, pero no muestra ningun resultado. Hay algún método aparte de usar hooks para poner una etiqueta en la pagina de checkout? y si no, que de malo tiene mi codigo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola te sugiero leas el codex de woocommerce, aqui encontraras lo que buscas.

https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/